# Android Asynchronous Http Client : @Override onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String content)

Tags: android, http, header, overriding, loopj

I'm trying to get cookie from server response (from Headers).

I  built library from source : https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http and add it to my project.
Here i try to override metod

```
client.post(context, link,  requestEntity, contentType, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {            
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String content) {
        Log.d("headers", String.valueOf(headers));
        onSuccess(statusCode, content);
    }
});
```

but get error :

> The method onSuccess(int, PreferenceActivity.Header[], String) of type
>   new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){} must override or implement a
>   supertype method

[AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/src/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java#L122)

How I can override this metod or get Headers?

Comment: Check your imports, `PreferenceActivity.Header[]` does not look like a type for `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Headers type supposed to be **org.apache.http.Header[]**  instead of Header[]

Answer (score 0):

I have ever faced with this problem. Try to open your gradle (**Gradle Scripts**), edit your **build.gradle(Module:app)** by adding:

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

after your gradle running, try `import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;`

I hope it will help you :)