# Unknown error in upload image :class anonymous class derived from asynchttpResponsehandler must either be declared abstract

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a novice
If possible check out the following code I don't understand the problem My program is trying to upload a file to the server. But in this part of the code there is an error That is not understandable to me

error:class anonymous class derived from asynchttpResponsehandler must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onsuccess()in asynchttpResponsehandler

```
package com.ehhg.upap1;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
 import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
 import android.support.v4.text.PrecomputedTextCompat;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.PrecomputedText;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.Manifest;
 import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
 import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest;
 import com.loopj.android.http.*;
 import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
 import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException;
 import java.security.acl.Permission;
 import java.util.jar.Manifest.*;
 import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.mime.Header;


public void uploadImage(File file) {
    AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("file", file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    myClient.post(url + "android/upload.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

      @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                            .load(url + "android/uploads/" + jsonObject.getString("filename"))
                            .into(img);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), new String(responseBody), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Most likely you imported the wrong `Header` class. Please check if this question helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946133/android-asynchronous-http-client-override-onsuccessint-statuscode-header

Comment: as commented by other users,it can be issue in import statement, please share import statements too.

Comment: As I suspected, you've imported a wrong `Header` class - it should be `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` must implement the `onSuccess` function.

Edit: After checking your, imports as commented by other user, you have imported wrong Header class. You need to import `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header` instead of `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.mime.Header` class.

Look code below for understanding

```
myClient.post(url + "android/upload.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    // following line is uncommented
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                        .load(url + "android/uploads/" + jsonObject.getString("filename"))
                        .into(img);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), new String(responseBody), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `@Override` annotation is optional, it shouldn't affect the compilation.

Comment: If @ Override is announced a new problem will be added  error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
              @Override

Comment: please share import statements

Comment: "
please share import statements – Massab 2 mins ago
"I do not understand what you mean